# How does one ensure that a user can delete only specific records?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, postgresql

When directly writing sql commands, it is easy to specify which records to delete (for example, by specifying an ID etc).

But in a webpage, if you have a list of links specifying different records (with the id embedded as a query parameter), how can you ensure that the user just doesn't edit the id in the link, so that he can delete a different record ?

For example, say I have the following link:

```
<a href="foo.com/deleterecord/1121">delete</a>
```

The user could easily copy paste the link, and change 1121 to 1123, and delete some other records that he shouldn't have access to.

So my question is, in your architecture, how do you allow the user to select which record to delete (by clicking on a link), but at the same time prevent a user from editing the link to delete other records ? Or is this handled at the database layer ?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/ddl-rowsecurity.html

Comment: You should check everything in the server side. Also, I'd send the http via $_post instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method to reduce (not *remove*) the risk of having a user viewing/editing a record different than the one you sent a link for is to use two keys that are not related to each other. The 2nd key could be a meaningful one or just a random number.

```
create table foo (pk serial, validation_key integer, data [...]);
Select * from foo where pk = 1121 and validation_key = 123456789;
```

A more robust method would be to encode the primary key when you generate the link, and to validate that the given pk and the decoded value match.

```
<a href="foo.com/deleterecord/1121/ABC123DEF456==">delete</a>
```

As others have mentioned, the real control occurs on the server side.

Answer (score 4):

Basically you can not prevent the editing of link, or better, you can not prevent a client to call some edited link. The simplest and safest thing to do is verify server-side the user identity and relative permissions.